# Update numpy array row by condition

Tags: numpy

I need help) I have NumPy array:

```
False False False False
False True  True  False
True  True  True  True
False True  True  False
False False False False
```

How can I get this (take first and last rows, that contains **True**, and set all of them elements to **False**)?

```
False False False False
False False False  False
True  True  True  True
False False False  False
False False False False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr[arr.any(axis=1).nonzero()[0][[0,-1]]] = False
```

**How it works:**

```
In [19]: arr

Out[19]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

`arr.any(axis=1)` finds which rows contains a `True` value:

```
In [20]: arr.any(axis=1)
Out[20]: array([False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

`nonzero` returns a tuple (one item for each axis) of indices of the `True` rows:

```
In [21]: arr.any(axis=1).nonzero()
Out[21]: (array([1, 2, 3]),)
```

We can use indexing to find the index of the first and last row containing a `True` value:

```
In [22]: arr.any(axis=1).nonzero()[0][[0,-1]]
Out[22]: array([1, 3])
```

And finally, we can set those rows to `False` with

```
In [23]: arr[arr.any(axis=1).nonzero()[0][[0,-1]]] = False

In [24]: arr
Out[24]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: @erthalion Does this answer the question generally?  I interpret the question as: if a row has both `True` and `False` values, then set all values to `False`.  Not just the first and last rows that fit that condition.  If more than two rows fit that condition, this answer misses some.  I would just do: `arr[~a.all(1)] = False`.

Comment: @askewchan: Yes, in the my question I thought about the first/last rows only.

Answer (score 1):

In case you meant "first and last" only in reference to the particular example ...

If every row that contains both `True` and `False` values should be set to `False`, then you shouldn't restrict to the "first and last" of these rows, and the solution is much easier.  Using the fact that `~a.all(1)` will tell you which rows are *not* all `True`, you can set those rows to `False` with:

```
arr[~arr.all(1)] = False
```

or, to avoid redundantly setting rows of entirely `False` to `False`, use *exclusive or*, `^`:

```
arr[arr.any(1) ^ arr.all(1)] = False
```

which will be faster in some circumstances.